# bridge rectifier

Tags: rectifier, bridge

I've got a PCB board with a bridge rectifier with PIN (AC + AC -)
I think I made a mistake because almost all bridges are (+ AC AC -)
I try to find any bridges of 3-5A on Aliexpress but I didn't find any.

Anyone can help me with a part #
Thanks

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

If you are buying from AliExpress you won't get datasheets and you are on your own. Our recommendation is "No datasheet? No sale!" This is because the datasheet will explain the connections and give proper ratings, de-ratings, pinout, charts, dimensions, etc. You have no traceability of quality or genuineness of the parts on AliExpress and they could be forgeries. Documentation and quality checks costs money to produce, maintain, store and publish. That's why quality suppliers are a little more expensive.

[image]

*Figure 1. What you want. (The pin-out is the style you want. I did not check the specification for this part.)*

[image]

*Figure 2. What you've got.*

Just bend the leads of the '+' and adjacent 'AC' leads with a long-nosed pliers to make a pretty cross-over between the two leads with enough clearance that you are confident that they won't touch. Insert the bridge into the board and solder up. It will stand off the board a few mm.